# search table whitin string php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

I submit a post to my database: `" Hello #Today is an illusion"`, It creates the next:

```
table_post: id_post  | post
                3       Hello #Today is an illusion

table_hashtags: id_hashtag  | hashtag
                    1          #Today

 table_hashtags_relation: id_relation  | id_hashtags  | id_post
                                1           1               3
```

It saves the hashtag `#today` `id_hashtag=1` and relates it with the post number 3

if I edit the post to: `"Hello #Tomorrow is an illusion"` it saves `#tomorrow` as `id_hashtag=2` and relates it too to post number 3.

How do I search,first, for `#today` in the edited post in order to delete it? (and delete its relation too),so that the table results like this?

```
table_post: id_post  | post
                3       Hello #Tomorrow is an illusion

table_hashtags: id_hashtag  | hashtag
                    2          #Tomorrow

table_hashtags_relation: id_relation  | id_hashtags  | id_post
                                2           2               3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query to retrieve all id_relation from table_hashtag_relation with id_post.. then you can query to pull all the hashtag from table_hashtag.. then delete the desired hashtag..

Comment: If you system insert a new entry to hashtag and hashtag_relation table every time you make a change then you will need to delete the current one before the system execute the insert query..

Comment: i would store the id_hashtag, id_relation and id_post in a hidden field and on submission will delete the old one..

Comment: yes, I have that idea too, but I need to know how do I search for the all hastags not related anymore and delete them

Comment: would you please try a solution in SQL? I think storing the ids wouldn be suitable for my coding

Comment: First you need to stop more hashtag being on the database when the new one added or post edited.. and before i tell you exactly, can you confirm if th hashtag_relation table doesnt store the old hashtag?

Comment: Yes anytime I submit a post all the relations are stored in table_relations. I want to delete that relation once the post is edited and the hashtag is discarded for a new one.

Comment: I think yoy dont know the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126876/discussion-between-max-and-mahaidery).